# Why Should Homebrew be used to Install Python?

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

I have been reading a lot of the tutorials around the web and answers on the site about using `Homebrew`. When it comes to `Python` though, the advice leaves me with more questions than answers.

I understand the how, but none of the answers I have seen so far have really explained the why behind using `Homebrew` to install `Python` and what the benefits are to installing `Python` with `Homebrew` as opposed to using `OS-X` installers provided by the Python Foundation?

The newest versions of the installers from Python and the current implementation of `PIP` seem to be working pretty well, so I would really appreciate any input on my question. I have worked with Python for a while but from more of a tactical, one off problem solving perspective and I am brand new to tools like `Brew` and version control software such as `Git`. I am trying to get up the learning curve. Finding an answer to why I would choose to go with a `Homebrew` install over just heading over to python.org and downloading from them and then using pip to install packages might help me to understand the benefits of a tool like `Homebrew`.

So I guess, what does `Homebrew` give me that going through the installation put in place by TPF does not?

Are there advantages/disadvantages to where `Homebrew` installs `Python` and Python packages over  the `/Library/Frameworks/` and the `site-packages` folder within that framework?

Though this last question is too broad and likely out of scope, if anyone would also address or provide a link to a good answer on what the benefits are of using `Homebrew` in general, I'd appreciate it?

Thank you,

Comment: Then you have virtualenv to add to the mix too. Too many cooks!

Comment: Also you end up with things like python3 and pip3 - and end up needing to put aliases in ~/.zshrc to get rid of the 3.

Answer (score 9):

The big advantage of using a package manager like Homebrew is it makes it easier to keep your Python installation up to date.  If you download Python from the website, then to update it means you'll need to go back to the website and download a new copy of Python (or whatever it is that you need to update that could have been installed with Homebrew).

Also, when downloading installers, I find they tend to clutter up my downloads folder and require me to periodically clean up unused files.  I'd rather spend my time coding instead of managing my disk space usage.

When it comes to updating any package with Homebrew, the command is simple:

```
brew upgrade
```

And this will update all outdated packages that you installed with Brew.

Now, this isn't something unique to Homebrew. Macports, PIP, npm, Maven, and other package management tools are also able to manage the versions of modules or tools you install.

For more information, see [Safari Books Online - Keeping Your Homebrew Up To Date](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/18/keeping-homebrew-date/).

Comment: Hi @jmort253. Thanks for the response and the link. I am working through it now. I saw that the same author also wrote [Getting Started With Homebrew](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/03/homebrew/) so I am starting there.

Comment: Would a very liberal analogy be that a package manager is to Open Source what the Mac App Store is to Apple sandboxed distributed software?

Comment: A very loose analogy, but it is an analogy nonetheless.  The Apple store mostly contains software or software tools. Package managers can also contain software and tools, but some manage dependencies in a software project.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

A few reasons not to use system python on OS X from [this post](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x),

> - Apple doesn’t always do a good job on keeping the Python runtime environment up to date,
> - it can be cumbersome to play with permissions just to install third-party Python libraries,
> - finally, Apple has a tendency to wipe-out your site-packages with every major OS upgrade.

The use of an independent package manager for Python modules, such as Homebrew, conda, Macports,  ets. is thus preferred.

Comment: Hi @rth. Thank you for the response. Yes, I understood the benefits of having a user installed instance of Python versus developing with the Apple version and wasn't questioning that wisdom. I even understand why you might use a distribution like EPD or Anaconda over TPF's.  My question is more along the lines of why a package manager and not just TPF dmg and PIP. I am probably trying to wrap my head around package managers as a tool, as I am relatively new to the idea of open source development.

Comment: @AMR Well then you are essentially comparing one package manager (pip) to another one (Homebrew). Both could work. I guess on OS-X, Homebrew is more practical in also handles classical linux packages. Say, you want to install  pillow that depends on `libjpeg`. If you are lucky OS-X will have the right version of `libjpeg`, and  `pip install pillow` will be sufficient. More likely, though, it will ship some outdated version and you would need to compile/install the right version of libjpeg manually (just an illustration). This becomes very quickly tedious, and Homebrew automates that for you.

Comment: Okay. So if the dependencies of the package, say pillow, are not pypi related packages, then pip doesn't take care of those dependencies, however a different package manager like Homebrew or MacPorts might?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the main difference. It's not that pip doesn't care, but it just cant do anything about it.  On linux `apt-get`, etc. allows you to manage those packages, so  `pip` is sufficient for all Python modules. On Mac though, if you don't want to compile things manually from source, you need a package manger like Homebrew that handles non Python dependencies of Python packages.

Comment: I made a mistake in the comments above. It is the Python Software Foundation and its acronym is **PSF** not **TPF**. I would have edited, but I am not getting that option. So where I said **TPF**, I meant **PSF**. Sorry for the confusion.